# ¿Como guardar la fecha y hora automáticamente en laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

en mi proyecto los usuarios pueden hacer recarga y en la tabla **recargas** tengo un campo que se llama **fecha_recarga** el cual es de tipo DataTime por tal motivo nesesito saber como puedo guardar la fecha y hora actual sin usar un campo como `<input type="date">` , porque no quiero que el usuario pueda manipular la fecha y la hora de la recarga sino que la coja del sistema .

**tabla recargas**

```
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('recargas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('usuario_id')->unsigned();
        $table->decimal('cantidad_recarga' , 8,2);
        $table->dateTime('fecha_recarga');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('usuario_id')->references('id')->on('usuarios');
    });
}
```

**Modelo Recarga**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $recargas = new Recarga();
        $recargas->usuario_id = $request->Usuario;
        $recargas->cantidad_recarga = $request->Cantidad_Recarga;
        //Aqui Quiero Guardar La Feha
        $recargas->fecha_recarga = 
        $recargas->save();

        return redirect('recargas');
    }
```

Mi formulario donde guardo las recargas

```
    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('recargas.index') }}"> Ver Usuario  </a>
<form style="width: 400px;border:0px red solid;margin:auto"  method="POST" action="{{ asset('/recargas') }}">
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="Nombre">Usuario</label>
       <select name="Usuario" id="Usuario" class="form-control">
         @foreach ($usuarios as $usuario)
       <option class="form-control" value="{{$usuario->id }}"> {{$usuario->nombre }}</option>
         @endforeach      
      </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group col-md-12">
       <label for="Cantidad_Recarga">Cantidad De Recarga</label>
       <input type="Cantidad_Recarga" class="form-control" name="Cantidad_Recarga" id="Cantidad_Recarga"  value="" placeholder="Cantidad Recarga">
     </div>
   </div>
   {{csrf_field()}}
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Recargar</button>
 </form>
 <br>
```

Comment: Podrías probar con `Carbon` en tu caso seria algo así `$recargas->fecha_recarga = Carbon::now();` Recuerda importar `Carbon`

Comment: Lo Importo Asi 

**use Carbon\Carbon;**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te puede funcionar hacerlo así como te comentaba en la otra publicación

al inicio de tu controller poner esto

Primero invoca al `namespace` de Carbon para poder usarlo y obtener en este caso la fecha actual que te sirve por que me comentaste que tienes un campode tipo datetime

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

$fecha = Carbon::now();

$registro = new ModelName();
$registro->columnaNombre1 = $request->input("valorUno");
$registro->columnaNombre2 = $request->input("valorDos");
$registro->fechaColumna = $fecha;
$registro->save();
```

Para establecer la zona horaria y que te devuelva el dato correcto, puedes dentro de `app/AppServiceProvider.php` en el método `boot` declarar lo siguiente

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
```

Entonces para ver la diferencia, antes de usar la línea de código que pongo arriba el dato me aparecía así

```
2019-02-09 06:03:00
```

Posterior a su uso ahora tengo el dato así

```
2019-02-09 00:03:23
```

Aquí tienes la guía oficial de zonas horarias y como declararlas en PHP, solo usa la que te corresponda

http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.america.php

Del mismo modo puedes ir a `app/config/app.php` y en la zona de `timezone` colocar la zona horaria de este modo

```
'timezone' => 'America/Mexico_City',
```

Y con esto ya no es necesario hacer el primer paso que te comenté

Comment: ya lo hice pero me agrego una hora la cual no es **2019-02-09 05:57:18**

Comment: te agrego una actualización con una forma de tratar ese asunto @NeiiderMartinezRivas

Comment: muchas gracias , solo cambie **Mexico_City** por la de mi pais y todo funciona perfecto Muchas Gracias Por Todo.

Comment: También se pudo modificar directamente en la configuración, `config\app.php` en la clave `timezone` , aunque depende del alcance de la aplicación, caso contrario podría utilizar `mutadores`  y/o  `accesores`  para manejar las zonas horarias.

Comment: si @Dev.Joel de hecho cuando el OP me calificó estaba editando para agregar esa opción, pero de todos modos la pondré, me tarde en ponerlo por que primero hago el ejercicio lo compruebo y luego ya respondo :)

Answer (score 2):

Parece que todos aquí tienen sus conocimientos desactualizados en Laravel:

Desde Laravel 5.5 existe el helper `now()`, es todo lo que necesitas para obtener la fecha y hora actual, no hay que importar Carbon ni crear una nueva instancia, nada de eso.

Tan solo:

```
$recargas->fecha_recarga = now();
```

Invito a todos a que revisen la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-now